# VBA- Opening hyperlinks from a List to copy specific data into a master sheet

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I currently am using the below code to generate a list of hyperlinks from a specific folder. I am trying to figure out how to access each of those hyperlinks to copy and paste certain data into a master spreadsheet then close the document in a loop. The data is located on the same tab for each file but In each file the number of Columns are always the same but not always the number of rows. Im trying to figure out how to capture all of that info into a master sheet without blanks and without overwriting data from the file before.

```
Option Compare Text
Option Explicit

Function Excludes(Ext As String) As Boolean
     'Function purpose:  To exclude listed file extensions from hyperlink listing

    Dim x, NumPos As Long

     'Enter/adjust file extensions to EXCLUDE from listing here:
    x = Array("exe", "xlsm", "xml")

    On Error Resume Next
    NumPos = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Ext, x, 0)
    If NumPos > 0 Then
        Excludes = True
    Else
        Excludes = False
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function

Sub HyperlinkFileList()
     'Macro purpose:  To create a hyperlinked list of all files in a user
     'specified directory, including file size and date last modified
     'NOTE:  The 'TextToDisplay' property (of the Hyperlink object) was added
     'in Excel 2000.  This code tests the Excel version and does not use the
     'Texttodisplay property if using XL 97.

    Dim fso As Object, _
    ShellApp As Object, _
    File As Object, _
    SubFolder As Object, _
    Directory As String, _
    Problem As Boolean, _
    ExcelVer As Integer, _
    TotalD As String, _
    Wb As Workbook, _
    Ws As Worksheet


     'Turn off screen flashing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

     ' Clear sheet
    Cells.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    'Useless : Range("A1").Select

     'Create objects to get a listing of all files in the directory
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

     'Prompt user to select a directory
    Do
        Problem = False
        Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application"). _
        Browseforfolder(0, "Please choose a folder", 0, "D:\JBOSS\Testdossier")
        'Browseforfolder(0, "Please choose a folder", 0, "D:\JBOSS\Testdossier")

        On Error Resume Next
         'Evaluate if directory is valid
        Directory = ShellApp.self.Path
        Set SubFolder = fso.GetFolder(Directory).Files
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            If MsgBox("You did not choose a valid directory!" & vbCrLf & _
            "Would you like to try again?", vbYesNoCancel, _
            "Directory Required") <> vbYes Then Exit Sub
            Problem = True
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    Loop Until Problem = False

     'Set up the headers on the worksheet
    With ActiveSheet
        With .Range("A1")
            .Value = "Listing of all files in:"
            .ColumnWidth = 40
             'If Excel 2000 or greater, add hyperlink with file name
             'displayed.  If earlier, add hyperlink with full path displayed
            If Val(Application.Version) > 8 Then 'Using XL2000+
                .Parent.Hyperlinks.Add _
                Anchor:=.Offset(0, 1), _
                Address:=Directory, _
                TextToDisplay:=Directory
            Else 'Using XL97
                .Parent.Hyperlinks.Add _
                Anchor:=.Offset(0, 1), _
                Address:=Directory
            End If
        End With

        With .Range("A2")
            .Value = "File Name"
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 15
            .ColumnWidth = 50
            With .Offset(0, 1)
                .ColumnWidth = 15
                .Value = "Date Modified"
                .Interior.ColorIndex = 15
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            End With
            With .Offset(0, 2)
                .ColumnWidth = 12
                .Value = "File Size (Kb)"
                .Interior.ColorIndex = 15
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            End With

        End With
    End With

     'Adds each file, details and hyperlinks to the list
    For Each File In SubFolder
            If Not Excludes(Right(File.Path, 3)) = True Then
                With ActiveSheet
                     'If Excel 2000 or greater, add hyperlink with file name
                     'displayed.  If earlier, add hyperlink with full path displayed
                    If Val(Application.Version) > 8 Then 'Using XL2000+
                        .Hyperlinks.Add _
                        Anchor:=ActiveSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0), _
                        Address:=File.Path, _
                        TextToDisplay:=File.Name
                    Else 'Using XL97
                        .Hyperlinks.Add _
                        Anchor:=ActiveSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0), _
                        Address:=File.Path
                    End If
                    'Add date last modified, and size in KB
                    With .Range("A65536").End(xlUp)
                        .Offset(0, 1) = File.datelastModified
                        With .Offset(0, 2)
                            .Value = WorksheetFunction.Round(File.Size / 1024, 1)
                            .NumberFormat = "#,##0.0"
                        End With
                    End With
                    'Add Total From this file to current workbook
                    Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(File)
                    Set Ws = Wb.Sheets("Summary")
                On Error Resume Next


                    Wb.Close
                    Set Wb = Nothing
                    Set Ws = Nothing
                End With
            End If
    Next File

     'Turn back on screen updating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You've told us what you are trying to do and gave us a code dump, which is not much of a meaningful question. Read [ask] and [mcve] or take a [tour] to understand how we can better help you.

Comment: You're pretty close to resolve your issue. Instead of adding hyperlinks, inside a loop open workbook, copy the data you want to insert into "master sheet", then close workbook. Please, check [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1187802/Copy-Data-Between-Excel-Sheets-using-VBA)

Answer (score 0):

Exactly!  Why are you messing around with Hyperlinks?  Just open a file, grab the data you need, close the file, and move on to the next one to do the same.

```
Sub Basic_Example_1()
    Dim MyPath As String, FilesInPath As String
    Dim MyFiles() As String
    Dim SourceRcount As Long, Fnum As Long
    Dim mybook As Workbook, BaseWks As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range, destrange As Range
    Dim rnum As Long, CalcMode As Long

    'Fill in the path\folder where the files are
    MyPath = "C:\Users\Ron\test"

    'Add a slash at the end if the user forget it
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    End If

    'If there are no Excel files in the folder exit the sub
    FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xl*")
    If FilesInPath = "" Then
        MsgBox "No files found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Fill the array(myFiles)with the list of Excel files in the folder
    Fnum = 0
    Do While FilesInPath <> ""
        Fnum = Fnum + 1
        ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To Fnum)
        MyFiles(Fnum) = FilesInPath
        FilesInPath = Dir()
    Loop

    'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Add a new workbook with one sheet
    Set BaseWks = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)
    rnum = 1

    'Loop through all files in the array(myFiles)
    If Fnum > 0 Then
        For Fnum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
            Set mybook = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(Fnum))
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not mybook Is Nothing Then

                On Error Resume Next

                With mybook.Worksheets(1)
                    Set sourceRange = .Range("A1:C1")
                End With

                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    Err.Clear
                    Set sourceRange = Nothing
                Else
                    'if SourceRange use all columns then skip this file
                    If sourceRange.Columns.Count >= BaseWks.Columns.Count Then
                        Set sourceRange = Nothing
                    End If
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0

                If Not sourceRange Is Nothing Then

                    SourceRcount = sourceRange.Rows.Count

                    If rnum + SourceRcount >= BaseWks.Rows.Count Then
                        MsgBox "Sorry there are not enough rows in the sheet"
                        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
                        mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                        GoTo ExitTheSub
                    Else

                        'Copy the file name in column A
                        With sourceRange
                            BaseWks.cells(rnum, "A"). _
                                    Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = MyFiles(Fnum)
                        End With

                        'Set the destrange
                        Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("B" & rnum)

                        'we copy the values from the sourceRange to the destrange
                        With sourceRange
                            Set destrange = destrange. _
                                            Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
                        End With
                        destrange.Value = sourceRange.Value

                        rnum = rnum + SourceRcount
                    End If
                End If
                mybook.Close savechanges:=False
            End If

        Next Fnum
        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
    End If

ExitTheSub:
    'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With
End Sub
```

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win008.htm

Comment: I needed to have all the links located in a list to easily access the worksheets in addition to the macro itself. I forgot to post back on this thread bc i figured out how the code i needed to accomplish this. Thanks for the help though